# argumental reference inconsistency in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5, ecma262

I have recently encountered a nasty issue in JS.

Let say we pass a map, an array of objects to a function f.

```
var o=[{a:0}];
function f(a){
    for(var i in a){
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            a[i]=null;
        }
    }
    return a;
};
var outp=f(o);

alert(outp[0]+" === "+o[0]+" : "+(outp[0]===o[0]));

// here we expect loose equality, and equality in type, 
//furthermore it should identically equal as well, and we got right!
```

But, we can not pass total responsibility of an object to a function as argument, same like in functional paradigm `o=(function(o){return o})()`, because any kind of modification to o is not referenced!

```
var o=[];
function ff(a){
    return (a=undefined);
};
var outp=ff(o);
alert(outp+" === "+o.constructor+" : "+(outp===o));
// here we expect true, but we got false!
```

Why is the above described reference loss and 
presumably different referencce handling in the second use case, 
though in both case, functions got the array argument in the 0. position?

Comment: You simply assign a new value to the **local** variable `a`. You don't modify the value it references. Everything is passed by value in JavaScript, not by reference (in case of objects and arrays, the "value" is a reference to the object and array, not to the variable that holds the reference). That's similar in other languages, e.g. Python and Java.

Comment: You should not loop through arrays with `for-in`-loops, even if you use `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: @bergi: of course i can!
it is simply better to have consistent data structure management, and we can exclude unexpected properties, like length, or statically attached ones.
So if we let our enumerables "be clean", than we shouldn't be afraid of having one looping interface to our data structures.

Comment: I have mentioned length as unexpected property, but it seems length is rather a prototypal, then an owned property in modern browsers!

Comment: @Bergi is right. I mean if you want to do it, no one's going to stop you, but it's not just a matter of keeping your structure clean *(which if you do that, I don't know why you're using `.hasOwnProperty()` in the first place)*. The `for-in` doesn't guarantee any particular order of enumeration. There's also a performance impact. The `.length` is most certainly an owned property, though it also exists in the prototype chain.

Comment: ...and if this post boils down to *"I want JavaScript to be different..."*, well, join the club.

Comment: Just to clarify: `length` is an own, but non-enumerable properties of all array instances.

Comment: @amnotiam:
A bunch of very smart people vote for for-in enumeration order guarantee against ECMA insistency from including in specs, respectfully:
mozilla.6506.n7.nabble.com/for-in-evaluation-order-td90791.html
hasOwnProperty is needed for a simplistic fault-tolerance of accidentally touched future prototypes.

Comment: @ZoltanLudanyi: Yes, it would seem nice if `for-in` guaranteed order when used on Arrays. But remember that JavaScript Arrays are just a special kind of Object *(an Array index is no different from a property on an Object)*, so there's some logic to the guarantee not being there. The desires of a bunch of very smart people has no impact on the reality that the order is not guaranteed. We can spend our lives wishing things were different, or we can ourselves be smart, and use the tools we were given in their intended and specified way... and avoid the cost of the `.hasOwnProperty()` hack.

Comment: @squint http://stackoverflow.com/users/1106925/squint

Here you are:
[enumerable.js](https://github.com/zludany/enumerable.js)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript always passes arguments by value, so this won't work:

```
 function foo(x) {
    x = 100;
 }

 y = 5
 foo(y)
 y == 100 // nope
```

However this does work:

```
 function foo(x) {
    x.bar = 100;
 }

 y = {}
 foo(y)
 y.bar == 100 // yes
```

In the second snippet x is still passed by value, but this very value is a reference (pointer) to an object. So it's possible in a function to dereference it and access what's "inside" the object.

Comment: The ES5 spec should provide ways to specify whether i want to pass value or reference to a function, as options are provided in PHP!

Comment: @ZoltanLudanyi: "pass by reference" is rarely a good idea. Ideally, functions should avoid side effects, and silently modifying the caller's scope is perhaps the worst side effect possible.

Comment: @ZoltanLudanyi: No. JavaScript just does not allow pass-by-reference. Function calls are specified in ES5 to be call-by-value. For what would you need it?

Comment: JS provides a lot of functional facilities.
Arguments passing only by value, like a referential beansack, is really among the bad parts, i believe!

Comment: @Zoltan: Many languages don't allow this and yet they are very powerful and popular, e.g. Python. You can have your opinion of course, but SO is the wrong place to discuss it.